# Filter joined table in where statement instead of subquery

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

This is my database models with EntityFramework for MySQL

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string? firstName { get; set; }
        public string? lastName { get; set; }
        public string? email { get; set; }
        public string? displayName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<UserRequest>? userRequests { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class UserRequest
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? action { get; set; }
        public string? domain { get; set; }
        public string? pathAccessing { get; set; }
        public string? applicationName { get; set; }
        public string? type { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
        public Guid userId { get; set; }
        public User? user { get; set; }
    }
```

In this models, 1 user can have multiple userRequest. So I will like to query whether user access this domains before.

In SQL statement, this will be my statement

```
select * from User u 
inner join UserRequest ur on ur.userId = u.id
where ur.domains in ("http://localhost", "http://localhost.dev")
```

This is my statement in linq

```
var domainsList = new string[] {"http://localhost", "http://localhost.dev"};
     var result = _DBContext.User
                   .Include(q=>
                      q.userRequests             
                   ).Where((t)=> t.userRequests.any(u=>domainsList.Contains(u.domain)));
```

Generated SQL statement

```
SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`displayName`, `u`.`email`, `u`.`firstName`, `u`.`lastName`, `u1`.`id`, `u1`.`action`, `u1`.`applicationName`, `u1`.`createdDate`, `u1`.`domain`, `u1`.`pathAccessing`, `u1`.`type`, `u1`.`userID`
      FROM `user` AS `u`
      LEFT JOIN `userRequest` AS `u1` ON `u`.`id` = `u1`.`userID`
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM `userRequest` AS `u0`
          WHERE (`u`.`id` = `u0`.`userID`) AND `u0`.`domain` IN ('http://localhost', 'http://localhost.dev'))
      ORDER BY `u`.`id`
```

The generated sql statement is using subquery instead of my expected simple where expression. My database is not large so subquery is slower than join+where expression in my case.

Is there a way I can rewrite my linq statement to have dotnet generate the SQL statement similar to what I expect? Or this is not possible in Linq?

Found a few similar question, but none is trying to achieve the end result I'm hoping for.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why do you `Include` the `userRequests`? That's not necessary. A query using `EXISTS` is not necessarily slow, on the contrary. Check if the tables have indexes the query requires.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is not the full statement I wish to write. Added include because I wanna eager load the last 5 userRequests from the user and filter them by domain and period. And this lead me to another issue which I'm still trying to find answer, which is not be able to break the .Where in .Include() into multi if condition. 

ie. if user input time, then I will like filter the createdDate, and if user input domain, then filter the domain field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove include and use join. Please follow the sample query syntax

```
    var query = from u in User
            join ur in UserRequest
                on u.ID equals ur.userID
                where (new string[] {'exampleofdomainList'}).Contains(ur.domain)
            select new { u, ur}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary (see my comment above) and a drawback is that it multiplies the results.

Comment: @Nahid, anyway I can split the where in the join statement into multi line? 
ie. I wanna condition it like when user having date input, then I will add in period filter for createdDate and if user input domain list, then I will add in domain filter and if user input both then add in both